# How to deal with dates in y axis python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I have a question about dates on y axis.
I want to plot the day of the year of first 30ºC at certain location for several years. I have a DataFrame with "mm-dd" data format and I want to plot these data as a function of the years.
I know how to deal with datatime data in the x-axis **but I am unable to set an datetime y-axis so in the y-axis I would have day-month values and in the x-axis I would have year values.**
**Any clue of how to do this?**

EDIT: I include the code for more context. The next is irrelevant to the plot problem, but I think it could be useful.
 What that fragment of code does is detect the values >30 in the DataFrame maximas_diarias_natural which is a 365x11 (daysxyear) matrix where the indexes are the dates. 
`first30date` is the datetime index of the values extracted from `maximas_diarias_natural`
The variable `z` extracts the day and the months of the first 30ºC of each year and te variable `s` is a datetime dd-mm format constructed from the values in `z`.

The problem is that Python doesn't appears to accept datetimes in y-axis

```
yeartoday = 2020
first30day_index = np.zeros(yeartoday-2010,float)
first30month_index = np.zeros(yeartoday-2010,float)
for i in range(1,yeartoday-2009):
    for j in range(0,366):
        if maximas_diarias_natural[j,i] >= 30:
            diaprimer30_index[i-1] = maximas_diarias_natural[j,(yeartoday-2010)+2]
            mesprimer30_index[i-1] = maximas_diarias_natural[j,(yeartoday-2010)+3]
            i = i+1

first30date = np.concatenate([[first30day_index],[first30month_index]],axis=0)
z = np.zeros(np.size(first30date,1),float)
first30date_dt = np.zeros(np.size(first30date,1),dt.datetime)
# To convert 2 dim array with day and months in 1 dim array wiht month-day
for i in range(0,np.size(first30date,1)):
    z[i] = str(int(first30date[1,i])) + str(int(first30date[0,i]))

z = [str(int(ele)) for ele in z] 
for i in range(0,np.size(first30date,1)-1):
    s = z[i]
    if s[0]!=1:
        s =  '0' + s[0:]
    if int(s[2])>3:
        s = s[:2] + '0' + s[2:]
    z[i] = s
    first30date_dt[i] = dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%m%d').date()
    first30date_dt[i] = '{:%m-%d}'.format(first30date_dt[i])
    i = i+1

first30date_dt = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(first30date_dt))

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
diasprimer30.plot(kind="line")
```

What I want is to reverse this graph: The dates in ascending order in the y-axis and the years in the x-axis
[image]

Comment: Please provide an example to reproduce, it will be easier to help you that way

Comment: Some parts are still missing. For example, what are `diasprimer30` and `maximas_diarias_natural`? Also, only the last 3 lines affect the plot. The rest seems irrelevant. Most probably, you should reverse the order of the date column in the dataframe `diasprimer30`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add all the code 'cause is quite large. ```fechaprimer30``` is the same that ```first30date``` (i will correct that later, I forgot to translate that variable. 
What that fragment of code does is detect the values >30 in the DataFrame ```maximas_diarias_natural``` which is a 365x11 (daysxyear) matrix where the indexes are the dates.
The variable ```z``` extracts the day and the months of the first 30ºC of each year and te variable ```s``` is a datetime dd-mm format constructed from the values in z.
The problem is that Python doesn't appears to accept datetimes in y-axis